# Multiple Jpanel keylistener space

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, frame, textfield

I have a frame which contains 4 different panels.One panels contains a music player which on pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> key start playing the music while other 3 panels contains textfields and some  submit buttons.Now my problem is that while typing text in any of those textfield it's taking the input but whenever I try to give space in those textfield it's playing that music instead of typing a space in the textfield.

Comment: I would guess you've attached your key listener to your outer panel, rather than just your music panel?

Comment: Hence the frequent suggestion to use keybindings and document listeners.

Comment: the listener is attached only to the music panel and not to anything else.

Comment: Code sample, or it didn't happen :-)

Comment: after removing the keyfocuslistener it's working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a frame which contains 4 different panels.One panels contains a
>   music player which on pressing space key start playing the music while
>   other 3 panels contains textfields and some submit buttons.Now my
>   problem is that while typing text in any of those textfield it's
>   taking the input but whenever i try to give space in those textfield
>   it's playing that music instead of typing a space in the textfield.

and

> the listener is attached only to the music panel and not to anything
>   else

- add KeyBindings to JFrame (contains 4 JPanels)
- output should be Swing Action
- override setEnabled in Swing Action
- add all JComponents (for users input only) to array
- add FocusListener or all JComponents (for users input only)
- on focusGained any a.m. JComponent added to array should be changed
- but how can to reset isEnabled(true) for Swing Action, only by Swing Timer

---

flamewars

- not users friendly, quite impossible, wrong idea with a bunch side effects
- wrong, wrong, everything is wrong, you can't to determine any KeyShortCuts that can be used as inputs chars to the JTextComponents, JSlider, JComboBox (autocomplete too), JTable with isCellEditable(true)
- SPACE is used as accelerator for JButton (KeyBindings implemented in API) too, etc...

---

use JToggleButton instead of JPanel,

- has two states
- can be undecorated, then looks like as JPanel (for example)
- use Icons, put there play (stop) Icons, text, see there a few times with animated gif
- SPACE is accelerator (on focusGained)
- accesible from MouseEvents too